# compiler framework for C code

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, llvm-clang

I am looking for a compiler framework that I can use to write some code optimizations and dataflow analysis for C source code. I know there is LLVM but I would like to work with source code rather than bytecode. I was looking into LLVM-dragonegg but I am not sure how easy would it be to implement dataflow passes using that?

Comment: To those who voted for closing this question: I would like to know why this is an off-topic question. I am just asking to see what are the available options out there, not for a recommendation or endorsement.

Comment: Try Clang, it's got a decent and easy to use API, even with nice Python wrapper (cindex).

Comment: P.S. Another option is to work on LLVM IR level, while keeping the debugging metadata in order to maintain a mapping from your modified IR to the original source code. Depending on what you want to do it may be a better way than analysing Clang ASTs.

Answer (score 1):

A [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) don't work on textual source code (but it [parses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) source code). It works on internal representations, such as [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)s. Each compiler has its own internal representation(s) and most of the [optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) work of a compiler is to *transform* its internal representations.

If you decide to work with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you could extend it with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (or, more painfully, with your own GCC plugin). But of course you'll need to understand in details the internal representations (*Gimple*, Generic Trees) and the compilation passes.

MELT is a lispy domain specific language, implemented as a GCC plugin, to extend GCC.